# Android Studio: Force tab to render

Tags: android, kotlin

So I have an application with 3 tabs. The thing is, when I pull one of the tabs up, I want the other two to render and never have to re-render while on these tabs.

In other words, clicking on any of these tabs will not cause onCreateView to be called again. Here is my pager adapter:

```
            return when (position) {
                0 -> {
                    ProfilePageFragment()
                }
                1 -> {
                    SwipeFragment()
                }
                2 -> {
                    MessagesFragment()
                }
                else -> {
                    MessagesFragment()
                }
```

When I click on tab0, tab1 is rendered, and when I click on tab1, tab2 is rendered. It seems I leave the rendering when I go 2 tabs in a certain direction, in which going back will cause a re render. (Please let me know if that didn't make sense)

How do I get rid of this, or increase this number so that the re-rendering doesn't happen with 3 tabs? I would assume it is one of the @override methods in the PagerAdapter. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer. Much more simple than I thought. Just return on the destroy method:

```
    override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
        return
    }
```